# Many to Many Relation query in Yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

```
SELECT c.* 
from content c 
inner join contentTags ct on c.id = ct.content 
inner join tags t on ct.tag = c.id 
where t.id = 1
```

How to write above query in Yii 2 using ActiveQueryInterface methods

Comment: `$query = new \yii\db\Query();
        $query->select(['c.*'])
            ->from("{{content}} c")
            ->innerJoin("{{contentTags}} ct", "c.id=ct.content")
            ->innerJoin("{{tags}} t", "ct.tag=c.id")
            ->where(['=', 't.id', 1])
            ->all()`

Answer (score 2):

If you are using ActiveRecords you can create relation like this in Content class:

```
public function getTags()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Tag::className(), ['id' => 'tag'])
                    ->viaTable('contentTags', ['content' => 'id']);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [AcitveQuery](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-activequery) and [innerJoin()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#innerJoin()-detail)

```
$data = (new \yii\db\Query())
    ->select('c.*')
    ->from('content c')
    ->innerJoin('contentTags ct', 'c.id = ct.content')
    ->innerJoin('tags t', 'ct.tag = c.id')
    ->where(['t.id' => 1])
    ->all();
```

Comment: Hi, Thank You it works, but is there any way that I can get the result containing an array of object `app\model\Content` just like we jet from `Content::find()->all();`